# how can I resolve this error in Reading xlsx dataset in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
with open("F:\MTechProjects\FirstProject\BL.xlsx") as fin:
    notes=fin.read()
print(notes)
```

this is what executed with all import required

```
UnicodeDecodeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-87e93887fc02> in <module>
     17 #About the data
     18 with open("F:\MTechProjects\FirstProject\Shashikala - Blood Deferral Dataset.xlsx") as fin:
---> 19     notes=fin.read()
     20 print(notes)

~\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py in decode(self, input, final)
     21 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):
     22     def decode(self, input, final=False):
---> 23         return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
     24 
     25 class StreamWriter(Codec,codecs.StreamWriter):

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 597: character maps to <undefined>
```

Got this error. Is there any other way to read xlsx files? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try passing `encoding` to `open()`. Something like this `open(r'F:\MTechProjects\FirstProject\BL.xlsx', encoding='iso-8859-1')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
file = open(filename, encoding="utf8")
```

If the error still persist, You can Ignore error.

```
open(filename, errors='ignore')
```

You can also check which encoding is your file using like:

```
with open('file_name.csv') as f:
    print(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

With pandas in python modules you can read excel file like this

```
import pandas as pd
data1=pd.read_excel('F:\MTechProjects\FirstProject\BL.xlsx')
```